# I got xcodebuild: WARINING, while I run the code 'flutter run'

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging

I typed 'flutter run' at terminal to run my flutter code.
But, It didn't work.
I got this error message.
My Macbook is M1. I think this show that I got 2 types of flutter debugger?
I don't know. let me know what am i have to do.
Thanks for all the support.

[image]

Comment: As per the error, please check the line lib/main.dart 115

Comment: I checked the line, and nothing is wrong.